# Unable to stub timestamp on a mock CLLocation object in Kiwi

Tags: ios, objective-c, mocking, kiwi

I'm writing some tests, where I need to

- stub a call to a mock CLLocationManager to return a particular
  CLLocation
- and in turn that CLLocation needs to have a timestamp that
  is in the past

Creating instances of CLLocation is easy enough, but the timestamp property on it is read-only and fixed to the point in time when the instance was created.
So, I planned to create a mock CLLocation, and stub the timestamp call too.

So, code looks like this:

```
[[CLLocationManager stubAndReturn:theValue(YES)] locationServicesEnabled];
NSDate *oldDate = [IPPOTestSupportMethods createNSDateSubtractingDays:2];
//TODO - Why is line below failing
[[expectedOldLocationMock stubAndReturn:oldDate] timestamp];
[[locationMgrMock stubAndReturn:expectedOldLocationMock] location];
```

In summary, I've got a CLLocationManager mock, I create an NSDate that is two days earlier than today. I want that date to be returned when I call

```
[cllocationmock timestamp];
```

However, I'm getting and ARC Semantic Issue.

```
IPPOLocationManagerDelegateImplKiwiTests.m:203:33: Multiple methods named 'timestamp' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes
```

Is this an issue in Kiwi, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work by using the selector-stubbing technique instead of the message pattern technique:

```
[expectedOldLocationMock stub:@selector(timestamp) andReturn:oldDate];
```

I get the same error as you when using the message pattern technique (`stubAndReturn:`):

> Multiple methods named 'timestamp' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

If you inspect this error in the Issue Navigator, you should see that it points to two different classes that declare a `timestamp` selector: class `UIAcceleration` declares

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSTimeInterval timestamp;
```

…and class CLLocation declares

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) NSDate *timestamp;
```

Note the structure of the "message pattern" stubbing technique:

```
[[someObject stubAndReturn:expectedValue] messageToStub]
```

The `stubAndReturn:` method returns an opaque object of type `id`. Thus, it's equivalent to this:

```
id invocationCapturer = [someObject stubAndReturn:expectedValue];
[invocationCapturer messageToStub];
```

Here, "messageToStub" is your `timestamp` selector. So you're saying to send the message `timestamp` to an unknown object of type `id`. Since at compile time we make no assertion about the type of the object being sent the timestamp selector, it can't know which version of that timestamp property you mean, and thus it can't determine the correct return type.

You can reproduce the same error by simply doing this:

```
id someUnknownObject;
[someUnknownObject timestamp];
```

The conclusion is that the message-pattern stubbing technique just won't work well when there are different declarations visible of the same selector name.

Comment: Thanks. That's worked for me to. Also thanks for the explanation. I was using stubAndReturn way of doing it because I personally found it more readable. So, the explanation makes clear why I can't use it.

Comment: [stubAndReturn](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Mocks-and-Stubs) does sometimes seem more readable, and it has the advantage that you can make a stub specific to a certain combination of parameter values.